# Не получается добавить opencv в QTCreator

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, qtcreator, linux-mint

Скачал opencv с репозитория. В профайле прописал [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

информацию о путях взял отсюда [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

прописал в коде

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    cv::Mat inputImage =cv::imread("/home/anton/mbuntu-11.jpg");
    cv::imshow("Display Image", inputImage);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

и получил кучу ошибок [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что я сделал неправильно? что мне нужно дописать, чтоб qt увидел путь к файлам библиотеки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю у вас не все библиотеки указаны линковщику. На это указывает возникающая ошибка. Для примера мой тестовый pro-файл. Прошу учесть тот факт, что мой пример сделан под windows в вашем же случае (linux) названия библиотек могут отличаться.

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = OpenCvTest
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += D:\opencv\build\include

LIBS += D:\opencv\opencv_bin\bin\libopencv_core410.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\opencv_bin\bin\libopencv_highgui410.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\opencv_bin\bin\libopencv_videoio410.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\opencv_bin\bin\libopencv_video410.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\opencv_bin\bin\libopencv_imgcodecs410.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\opencv_bin\bin\libopencv_imgproc410.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\opencv_bin\bin\libopencv_features2d410.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\opencv_bin\bin\libopencv_calib3d410.dll

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Ну и Mainwindow.cpp. Пример чисто условный, просто чтобы показать как я использовал вызов функций из ОpenCV.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //create GUI windows
    cv::namedWindow("Frame");
    cv::namedWindow("FG Mask MOG 2");
    //create Background Subtractor objects
    cv::Ptr<cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2> pMOG2 = cv::createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(); //MOG2 approach

    cv::VideoCapture capture("e:/temp/test.mp4");
    if(!capture.isOpened()){
        //error in opening the video input
        qDebug() << "Unable to open video file: e:/temp/test.mp4";
        close();
    }

    cv::Mat frame;
    while (1){
        if (!capture.read(frame)){
            qDebug()<<"Unable to read next frame.";
            close();
        }
        cv::imshow("Frame", frame);
        QThread::sleep(100);
        qApp->processEvents();
    }
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
}
```